# How to set save the variable in a PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

For example, I have a config.php:

```
//default config
$name = 'default name';
$mail = 'default mail';
```

And I want to use a form to let the user edit the variable, everything is just like the using database, but in this case the difference is it is implement on a PHP file

So, after I get `$_POST['name']; $_POST['mail'];`, how can I modify the variable and save it in that PHP?

Comment: Don't. Seriously, seriously, don't. If you want use editable data then use a database or use a structured configuration file in a sane format (such as ini, JSON, XML, etc). Trying to programatically edit PHP is seriously non-trivial.

Comment: Is this config file basically just a text file with settings in it?

Comment: it is just a textfile with variable eg.id , pwd , server name etc... that's rights.

Comment: @Quentin , Thanks, i use php because it is quite easy to implement, i only need to include the php and use the corresponding variable can start my job, but i need to edit it if i want to have some changes

Comment: What should i do if use the ini? how can i retrieve the data? assume there are two data: name="abc" , mail="abc@hotmail.com" Thank you

Comment: You read the file, then parse it. There's probably a library somewhere to make it easy. I'd never use PHP for anything complicated enough to need a config file.

Comment: Quentin only hints at part of the horror here - the complexity of parsing PHP is small fry compared the risks / stability / contention of self-modifying code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file needs to be in PHP? You can hack together a quick configuration array into an external file using [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export)

The config file `config.php`

```
$config = array(
  'name' => 'My Name',
  'email' => 'some@one',
);
```

Loading/saving the config file:

```
include 'config.php';  // Bring config into the current namespace
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {  // Update on POST
 $config['name'] = $_POST['name'];
 $config['email'] = $_POST['email'];
 file_put_contents('config.php', sprintf("<?php\n%s\n", var_export($config, true)));
}
print_r($config);
```

As with any user input you should be sure to filter the input against a whitelist to weed out dangerous data. For instance, `preg_replace('/\W/', '', $_POST['name'])` will remove unsafe data (non-word characters) from the user-supplied values.

Comment: it will miss out the <? ?> and $string= 
after i change the file using the code you provide thanks.

Comment: D'oh, you're right. I've updated the answer. Also note the ending `?>` is not required in `config.php` as EOF (End Of File) serves the same purpose as `?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$config = file_get_contents('config.php');
```

That should read the config file into a string.  Then you can search the string or use a regex to replace the `$name` value with the `$_POST['name']` value.

This should work

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$config = file_get_contents('config.php');
$pos = strpos($config, '$name');
$config = substr_replace($config, '$name = \'' . $name . '\'', $pos, strpos($config, ';', $pos) - $pos);
$pos = strpos($config, '$mail');
$config = substr_replace($config, '$mail = \'' . $mail . '\'', $pos, strpos($config, ';', $pos) - $pos);
file_put_contents('config.php', $config);
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use file_put_contents function to write the config to file and a custom function to build the content itself like this:

```
function generateConfig(){
    return "//default config"
    . '$name' . " ='{$_POST['name']}';"
    . '$mail' . " ='{$_POST['mail']}';";
}

file_put_contents("file.config", generateConfig());
```

It is a solution, but better one would be to use JSON, XML or Database.

Comment: **Danger**: PHP code injection vulnerability. This gives uses the ability to execute **any** PHP they like, including `system` calls.

Comment: Also, it won't actually work. Since the strings are double quoted, `$name` and `$mail` will be interpolated into the string.

Comment: You are right, my bad about the variables. But still, this is the way how some systems work at the startup. For example Joomla.